# pdb files appear in website publish folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have asp.net website which when published using build > publish website option in VS2010 and even when checking omit debug information option in website publish window,published folder still contains pdb files is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The informational text on the *Publish Web* dialog, says:

> Publish uses settings from "Package/Publish Web" and "Package/Publish
>   SQL" tabs in Project Properties.

So to prevent PDB files being published, you can:

1. Delete all the PDB files from the existing publish location, if any exist. (They *will not* be deleted automatically).
2. Right-click on your project -> Properties and select the *Package/Publish Web* tab.
3. Ensure the *Exclude generated debug symbols* box is checked.

Now when you publish your project, the PDBs will be omitted.

Comment: I believe this to be the correct answer over the accepted one.

Comment: There is no such dialog for Web Site projects, only for Web Applications.

Comment: I like this answer the best. I would still like to build the .pdbs in release, so I can add them to our Symbol server (for any analyzing of dump files from production), but exclude them from deploy.

Comment: What about the WinForms project? It does not have the `Package/Publish Web` tab. Where can I find the `Exclude generated debug symbols` box for it?

Answer (score 11):

Another way is to edit the `pubxml` file (under `Properties` / `PublishProfiles` of your web project).

I have then add `bin\**\*.pdb` (`**` is there to mean any hierarchy even none between `bin` and your `pdb` files) to the node `ExcludeFilesFromDeployment`.

The `pubxml` thus look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>bin\**\*.pdb</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 6):

**Follow the instructions step-by-step to prevent PDB files being generated after publish:**

I have attached screenshot with all steps using MS Visual Studio Community 2017 version:

[image: Settings to prevent PDB files]

Answer (score 3):

The PDB files will be there from your last build under debug.  Check the properties to check when they were modified or delete to see if they come back.

Comment: thanks eddy556, but i tried with empty folder as target location but found no luck, is that you meant?

Comment: No I meant to make sure your in release mode then just delete the PDB files, they shouldn't come back.

Comment: hi a strange thing, in build mode option i can only select debug mode but when i go to new configuration window there is no option of copy from release config any idea , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have precompile during publishing enabled:

Under publish settings tab click on file publish options to expand that section.

Next click on the configure link next to 'Precompile during publishing' option.  Then make sure Emit debug information is not checked in the popup window.